# Paperclip doesn't move files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, paperclip

I'm trying to do somethinkg I've done hundered of times, and today it will not work... And I have no idea why.

I try to create an object with an attached file, and when object is created, do some treatment on the attached file. Or, the file is not present at the specified place !

I have an other model in the same application, doing Imagemagick treatments, and files are in the right directories. Here is no image treatment.

Here is some code

```
class Test
  has_attached_file :file
  after_create :do_some_stuff
  def do_some_stuff
    raise "File not found" if !File.exists?(self.file.path)
  end
end
```

I obtain my `File not found` exception.

I tried to see if PostProcessing were executed, like this :

```
class Test
  has_attached_file :file
  after_post_process :print_log
  after_create :print_created
  def print_log
    $stderr.puts "Processed."
  end
  def print_created
    $stderr.puts "Created."
  end
end
```

The "Processed" is correctly printed before the after_create method...

Do you have any idea ?

My configuration :
Rails 2.3.18
Ruby 1.8.6
Rspec 1.3.2
Paperclip 2.3.0

Answer (score 1):

OK, my fault.

I read the code, and Paperclip call the `save` method with an `after_save`. And `after_save` is called after `after_create`.